# not delivering emails sent with nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, nodemailer

i trying to send emails with ***in NextJs using nodemailer*** and it works and the response is success and i watch mailtrap it look like the emails was sent, but the problem is in there that i didn't receive any email and i don't know why its happening and how can i fix this..

its My configure code

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

async function sendEmail(token, email) {
  try {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
      port: process.env.SMTP_PORT,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
        pass: process.env.SMTP_PASS,
      },
    });

    transporter.verify(function (error, success) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        // this console.log will print and every thing is OK!
        console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
      }
    });

    const message = {
      to: email,
      from: `${process.env.STMP_FROM_NAME} <${process.env.STMP_FROM_EMAIL}>`,
      subject: "Reset Password",
      html: `
        <p>
          You Tried to reset your password, then just click this
          <a href="http://localhost:3000/password/forget/${token}">link </a> to do
          this..
        </p>
      `,
    };

    await transporter.sendMail(message);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

export default sendEmail;
```

and its my controller codes

```
const sendResetMessage = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await Users.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

    if (!user) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler("User not found with this email", 404));
    }

    // Get reset token
    const resetToken = user.generateTokenToResetPassword();
    await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });

    await sendEmail(resetToken, user.email);

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: `Email sent to: ${user.email}`,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
    user.resetPasswordExpire = undefined;

    await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });
    return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500));
  }
});
```

[image: And its image that prove emails sent from mailtrap, but i didn't delivered any email]

Comment: Have you checked your spam/junk folder?

Comment: yeah bro i checked it, but not there. @brc-dd